# Make a Legacy Escape Function SQL injection Safe in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, security, mysqli, pdo

I have to deal with a very legacy large code base that uses following function to make the SQL queries SQL injection safe. I like to know how do i make it safe enough for SQL vulnerabilities and make the website Secure ?

```
function to_sql($Value, $ValueType = "Text") {
    global $DB_conn;
    if ($ValueType == "Plain") {
        return addslashes ( $Value );
    }
    if ($ValueType == "Number" || $ValueType == "Float") {
        return doubleval ( str_replace ( ",", ".", $Value ) );
    }
    if ($ValueType == "Check") {
        if ($Value == 1) {
            return "'Y'";
        }
        return "'N'";
    }
    if ($ValueType == "Text") {

        if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
                $Value = stripslashes($Value);
        }
        $Value=mysqli_real_escape_string($DB_conn,$Value);
        return "'" . $Value . "'";
    }
    else{
    return "'" . addslashes ( $Value ) . "'";
    }
}
```

This function is used as following in SQL queries ...

```
SELECT state_id, state_title 
FROM geo_state 
WHERE country_id=" . to_sql($country,"Number")  . " 
AND country_name='".to_sql($country_name,"Text")."' 
ORDER BY state_title;
```

***Note:***
**Please since its very large code-base its impossible to re-write all queries in new way like PDO or using mysqli functions, so i need solution that can resolve this SQL injection and Security Problems within this function itself.**

Comment: If you can't do the right thing, aggressively whitelist input. If you're using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` then slowly rolling out `mysqli_prepare()` should be possible too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get rid of `Plain` mode which adds no security at all and thus every case where it's being used makes your code essentially vulnerable.

To get rid of `else` clause is a good idea too, as it's just duplicates `Text` mode, but for lesser number of encodings.

Thus, I'd suggest to make `Text` mode default, get rid of `Plain` mode and eventually investigate the  code for the cases where `Plain` were used.

```
function to_sql($Value, $ValueType = "Text") {
    global $DB_conn;
    if ($ValueType == "Number" || $ValueType == "Float") {
        return doubleval ( str_replace ( ",", ".", $Value ) );
    }
    if ($ValueType == "Check") {
        return ($Value) ? "'Y'" : "'N'";
    }
    return "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($DB_conn,$Value) . "'";
}
```